# Import specific text file contents (to monkey macro's)

Tags: import

I have some metadata that I want to import from a (program generated) text file to several fields that are updated regularly. I have two possible situations for the text file:

- One file with *n* lines of text
- *n* files with one line of text

Say that these files contain for instance the names of some monkeys, and I want to be able to write the following MWE, where the name of monkey 1 and 2 are extracted from either `monkey1.txt` and `monkey2.txt` or from the file `monkeys.txt` with the two names on one line each.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\monkeyOne{Name of monkey 1}
\newcommand\monkeyTwo{Name of monkey 2}

\begin{document}

\monkeyOne{} just threw some poo at \monkeyTwo{}. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `\definemonkey` has three main arguments: the control sequence to define, the file name to load and the item number. In the ordinary version, the file `<filename><itemnumber>.txt` is used, in the *-variant line `<itemnumber>` from `<filename>.txt` is used. The file is read just once, for the *-form.

The trick is to use `\tl_set_from_file:Nnn` (the same as `\CatchFileDef`), with adding a nonstandard line terminator for the *-form, which is used to build a sequence, the proper item is then extracted from.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{monkey1.txt}
Name of monkey 1
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{monkey2.txt}
Name of monkey 2
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{monkeys.txt}
Name of monkey 1
Name of monkey 2
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definemonkey}{smmm}
 { % #2 = command name, #3 = file (prefix), #4 = number
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \holene_define_monkey_file:Nnn #2 { #3 } { #4 }
   }
   {
    \holene_define_monkey_single:Nnn #2 { #3 } { #4 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \holene_define_monkey_single:Nnn
 {
  \tl_set_from_file:Nnn #1 { \endlinechar=\c_minus_one } { #2#3.txt }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \holene_define_monkey_file:Nnn
 {
  \seq_if_exist:cF { l__holene_define_monkey_#2_seq }
   {
    \seq_new:c { l__holene_define_monkey_#2_seq }
    \tl_set_from_file:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { \endlinechar=`^^J } { #2.txt }
    \seq_set_split:cnV { l__holene_define_monkey_#2_seq } { ^^J } \l_tmpa_tl
   }
  \tl_set:Nx #1 { \seq_item:cn { l__holene_define_monkey_#2_seq } { #3 } }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { cnV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definemonkey{\monkeyOne}{monkey}{1}
\definemonkey{\monkeyTwo}{monkey}{2}

\definemonkey*{\monkeyOneA}{monkeys}{1}
\definemonkey*{\monkeyTwoA}{monkeys}{2}

\begin{document}

\monkeyOne{} just threw some poo at \monkeyTwo{}. 

\monkeyOneA{} just threw some poo at \monkeyTwoA{}. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This definitely will do the trick. I'm having trouble identifying a lot of the code you're writing in `xparse`, i.e. `\seq`, `\tl`, `\cs`, etc. and I can't find them in the documentation. Do you have some documentation to the commands you use?

Comment: @Holene `texdoc interface3`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start. There's a spurious space at the end of each name that should be deleted.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

% these files will be external in the application
\begin{filecontents}{monkey1.tex}
Nim Chimpsky
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{monkey2.tex}
Washoe
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand\monkeyOne{\input{monkey1}}
\newcommand\monkeyTwo{\input{monkey2}}

\begin{document}

\monkeyOne{} just threw some poo at \monkeyTwo{}. 

\end{document}
```